# Python ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape () doesn't match the broadcast shape (50,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting, cross-product

I'm using numpy to compute the cross product of two arrays, but I'm running into the following error:

`ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape () doesn't match the broadcast shape (50,)`

I have three variables which are of type numpy.ndarray and represent row vectors:

- `n = [0 0 1]`
- `beta = [array with 50 elements, 0, array with 50 elements]`
- `betap = [array with 50 elements, 0, array with 50 elements]`

The first and third elements of `beta` represent the result of the following piecewise functions:

```
t_start = (-2 * 0.01) / 299792458
t_end = (3 * 0.01) / 299792458
t = np.linspace(t_start, t_end)

x_of_t = = np.piecewise(t,
                      [np.logical_or(t < t_start, t > t_end), np.logical_and(t_start <= t, t <= t_end)],
                      [((0.01 * 0.02) / (2 * np.pi * 2)), (lambda t: (0.01 * 0.02) / (2 * np.pi * 2) * np.cos((2 * np.pi)/0.01 * 299792458 * t))])

z_of_t = np.piecewise(t, 
                      [t < t_start, t > t_end, np.logical_and(t_start <= t, t <= t_end)], 
                      [(lambda t: (np.sqrt(0.75) * 299792458 * (t - t_start) + np.sqrt(0.75) * (1 - 0.02**2 / (4 * np.sqrt(0.75) * 2**2)) * 299792458 * t_start - 0.01 * 0.02**2 / (16 * np.pi * np.sqrt(0.75) * 2**2) * np.cos(2 * ((2 * np.pi)/0.01) * 299792458 * t_start))), 
                       (lambda t: np.sqrt(0.75) * 299792458 * (t - t_end) + np.sqrt(0.75) * (1 - 0.02**2 / (4 * np.sqrt(0.75) * 2 **2)) * 299792458 * t_end - 0.01 * 0.02**2 / (16 * np.pi * np.sqrt(0.75) * 2 **2) * np.cos(2 * ((2 * np.pi)/0.01) * 299792458 * t_end)),
                       (lambda t: np.sqrt(0.75) * (1 - 0.02**2 / (4 * np.sqrt(0.75) * 2 **2)) * 299792458 * t - 0.01 * 0.02**2 / (16 * np.pi * np.sqrt(0.75) * 2**2) * np.cos(2 * ((2 * np.pi)/lambda_u) * 299792458 * t))])
```

The first and third elements of `betap` represent the derivatives of these functions. I am calculating the derivatives using numpy's gradient function `np.gradient(beta_x_of_t)` so the array lengths will match (len = 50). Similarly, when checking the shape of `n`, `beta`, and `betap`, they all have the same shape `(3,)`. Checking the shape of the first and third elements of `beta` and `betap` gives the following shape: `(50,)`.

Given that the shapes are the same, I thought I should be able to perform the cross-product using `np.cross(n-beta, betap)`, but I get the above error.

My goal here is twofold:

1. Understand what the error message means. For example, I've looked over many other questions posted here, but I haven't seem someone answer what it means for an output operand to be non-broadcastable.
2. Using that information, solve the error to compute the cross product.

Comment: If you looked at many other questions, you surely saw comments asking for a **traceback**.  Why haven't you provided that here?

Comment: What is the `shape` and `dtype` of `n-beta` and `betap`?  How does that compare to the documented expectations of `np.cross`?  Show clear code that generates these objects.  I code for `x_of_t` etc, and some sort of confusing description of `betap` etc, but no clear cut copy-n-pastable code.

Answer (score 0):

From the `np.cross` docs, 2 sample arrays:

```
In [51]: x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
    ...: y = np.array([[4,5,6], [1,2,3]])
    ...: 
In [52]: np.cross(x[0],y[0])
Out[52]: array([-3,  6, -3])
In [53]: np.cross(x,y)
Out[53]: 
array([[-3,  6, -3],
       [ 3, -6,  3]])
```

Thus, `cross` is taking 2 vector cross products.  So it can take (n,3) arrays, and return a (n,3) result.  (or (n,2) for a 2d vector cross).

And of course a cross with itself is 0

```
In [59]: np.cross(x,x)
Out[59]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Lets make a list like your `beta`:

```
In [60]: beta = [np.arange(3),0,np.arange(3)]
In [61]: beta
Out[61]: [array([0, 1, 2]), 0, array([0, 1, 2])]
```

`numpy` doesn't like to make an array from such a list:

```
In [62]: np.array(beta)
<ipython-input-62-f4485c3a6e4c>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array(beta)
Out[62]: array([array([0, 1, 2]), 0, array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

But let's try to perform `cross` on such a (3,) shaped array:

```
In [64]: barr = np.array(beta,object)
In [65]: barr
Out[65]: array([array([0, 1, 2]), 0, array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
In [66]: np.cross(barr, barr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-66-7218b4a081e0>", line 1, in <module>
    np.cross(barr, barr)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in cross
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1655, in cross
    cp0 -= tmp
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape () doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,)
```

That looks like your error.

`np.cross` is intended for use with (N,3) shaped numeric dtype arrays.  An object dtype array like your `beta` is wrong.  I'm not even sure what you intend to be happening.

Most of your question is extraneous, that has nothing to do with the error. Your question should have shown the traceback, and clearly stated the shape and dtype of the arguments.

Comment: I appreciate your response, however I think you only skimmed my question. I do clearly state the shape of beta, betap, and n. I also specify that beta, betap, and n are of type numpy.ndarray, therefore stating that beta is a list is incorrect.

Comment: I don't think the shape matters in this case, but it is the dtype that matters. np.cross should work with a (3, N) shaped numeric dtype array as well.

Comment: The object dtype also does not seem to matter. After converting beta into a column vector, the cross product can perform as normal

Comment: When answering questions I focus on the `traceback`, array `shape` and `dtype`,and reproducibility (a [mcve] if possible).  I was able to reproduce the error by giving `np.cross` (3,) shaped object dtype arrays.  Numeric dtype arrays with shape (3,N) do work if the `axis` parameter is specified.